# Time Changing Without Clicking Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The following code works fine as long as the time in the spinbox does not change. What I want is to do the set the time for a break. The first time it works perfectly but after that if I change the value in the spinbox, the system will check for new value instead of the value which was in the spinbox when the button is clicked.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title("Fusion Calculator")

first_break_time_label = Label(root, text='1st Break:')
first_break_time_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

first_break_time_hour = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=23, format='%02.0f')
first_break_time_hour.grid(row=0, column=1)

first_break_time_minute = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=59, format='%02.0f')
first_break_time_minute.grid(row=0, column=2)

first_break_time_second = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=59, format='%02.0f')
first_break_time_second.grid(row=0, column=3)

loop_active = False  # global variable set to false

def check_breaks():   # new loop function that runs set_breaks and reschedules
    set_breaks()      # for 1 second later.
    root.after(1000, check_breaks)

def set_breaks():
    check_break = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    first_break_time_value = f'{first_break_time_hour.get()}:{first_break_time_minute.get()}:{first_break_time_second.get()}'

    if check_break == first_break_time_value:
        popup_first_break = Toplevel(root)
        popup_first_break.title('Official Break')
        popup_first_break_title_bar = Label(popup_first_break, text='OFFICIAL BREAK', fg='Red')
        popup_first_break_title_bar.pack()
    else:
        pass

    global loop_active
    if not loop_active:   #  This will only run when loop_active is false
        loop_active = True   # Set loop_active to True so it doesn't run again
        check_breaks()

set_breaks_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Set', command=set_breaks)
set_breaks_button.grid(row=1, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to bind the button with a mouse click so that it will create an array and get the values into the array. But I am having hard time working with events.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy way to do it, would be to create a dictionary that holds each of the breaks values initially set to None, then to populate the dictionary the first time the button is pressed and start the loop at the same time, then have the loop check the dictionary on each iteration for the break times, and set the button command to a function that updates the dictionary when pressed.

For example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title("Fusion Calculator")

first_break_time_label = Label(root, text='1st Break:')
first_break_time_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

first_break_time_hour = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=23, format='%02.0f')
first_break_time_hour.grid(row=0, column=1)

first_break_time_minute = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=59, format='%02.0f')
first_break_time_minute.grid(row=0, column=2)

first_break_time_second = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=59, format='%02.0f')
first_break_time_second.grid(row=0, column=3)

loop_active = False  # global variable set to false

breaks = {
    1: None
}

def check_breaks():   # new loop function that runs set_breaks and reschedules
    set_breaks()      # for 1 second later.
    root.after(1000, check_breaks)

def update_break():
    first_break_time_value = f'{first_break_time_hour.get()}:{first_break_time_minute.get()}:{first_break_time_second.get()}'
    breaks[1] = first_break_time_value
    set_breaks()

def set_breaks():
    check_break = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if check_break == breaks[1]:
        popup_first_break = Toplevel(root)
        popup_first_break.title('Official Break')
        popup_first_break_title_bar = Label(popup_first_break, text='OFFICIAL BREAK', fg='Red')
        popup_first_break_title_bar.pack()
    global loop_active
    if not loop_active:   #  This will only run when loop_active is false
        loop_active = True   # Set loop_active to True so it doesn't run again
        check_breaks()

set_breaks_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Set', command=update_break)
set_breaks_button.grid(row=1, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

What might be a better option though would be to start the timed loop at the start of the program that way you can get rid of the loop active variable and extra check function.

Like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title("Fusion Calculator")

first_break_time_label = Label(root, text='1st Break:')
first_break_time_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

first_break_time_hour = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=23, format='%02.0f')
first_break_time_hour.grid(row=0, column=1)

first_break_time_minute = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=59, format='%02.0f')
first_break_time_minute.grid(row=0, column=2)

first_break_time_second = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=59, format='%02.0f')
first_break_time_second.grid(row=0, column=3)

breaks = {
    1: None
}

def update_break():
    first_break_time_value = f'{first_break_time_hour.get()}:{first_break_time_minute.get()}:{first_break_time_second.get()}'
    breaks[1] = first_break_time_value

def check_breaks():
    check_break = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if check_break == breaks[1]:
        popup_first_break = Toplevel(root)
        popup_first_break.title('Official Break')
        popup_first_break_title_bar = Label(popup_first_break, text='OFFICIAL BREAK', fg='Red')
        popup_first_break_title_bar.pack()
    root.after(1000, check_breaks)


check_breaks()
set_breaks_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Set', command=update_break)
set_breaks_button.grid(row=1, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works perfectly but when I am trying to implement it to my GUI application it doesn't work for the first button click. But works the second button click onward. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @MuneebAsmone I have no idea.  Do you have you app on a github repo?